# A better, cooler name for the Chat Room

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat, fun

Our [chat room is called **"Unix and Linux"**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux).

While this is all good, most (all?) of the other chat rooms in all
the other Stack Exchange sites have funnier, cooler names than
just their site names. Who are we to be behind?

So, in the spirit of the Holiday Season, I propose a competition
for a "better" name. One name per answer, please.

Strive for the amusing, the unexpected, the original. But also, of course, something suitable for the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange main chat room.

NOTE: Per @muru's suggestion, try sorting the answers by the active tab to see more recent responses to the question:

[image]

Comment: It might be good to have a note asking users to have answers sorted *active* as well, so that new suggestions get exposure.

Comment: @muru I'm not sure what your suggestion means. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @FaheemMitha The answers are sorted by score, by default. So, the highest voted answers get the most visibility, and most votes from new visitors. If people sort by post activity/recency, they'll get to see new suggestions first, getting them a reasonable share of votes.

Comment: @muru I see. Ok. Shall I add a note to that effect to the question?

Comment: so... is it over yet? i think there's a pretty clear winner anyway. the *scope* of this contest might benefit from a little specificity...

Comment: @mikeserv terdon thinks we should give it a few more days.

Comment: There are lots of great suggestions here, but some of them would not be easy to search for in Google, etc. Eg, "User Space", and those names directly derived from standard commands. This may or may not be desirable. :)

Comment: @terdon have you guys set a date on which this poll ends?

Comment: @muru yes, two weeks after posting. That's the 9th.

Comment: Congratulations to the winner!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

How about `chat` as a device?

#### /dev/chat

Comment: Good Idea! +1; I like something like [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33481/mount-dev-chat) name

Comment: Does all of Unix use `udev`? I thought that was mostly a Linux/Solaris/BSD? thing... I do like it though, but maybe `mount /dev/chat /chat` is better still, like @Pandya suggested.

Comment: @cat: `/dev`'s been around forever in UNIX, predates `udev` by a couple decades.

Comment: @Mat Considering Unix predates *me* by about 3 decades, I'm not surprised I didn't know that.

Comment: @cat Now we also have [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3823/66803) answer

Comment: Sounds totally like «девчат» in russian, which is some derivative of the «girls»; ⁺¹ though, that's funny.

Comment: I was thinking `>> /dev/chat` but I like this just fine....

Comment: Is it a char or block device?

Comment: I _like_ this, but am DV'ing in hopes of bringing the later entry [`#!/bin/chat`](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3828/1925) higher in the voting ranks.

Comment: @Caleb Thanks for your honesty, but strategic downvoting is not cool, in my opinion. Though I don't personally have a stake in the name of the chat room.

Comment: @FaheemMitha We can disagree, but do you have something better to suggest? It seems to me this is how the SE post voting system in general works: I think this answer is less desirable (useful) than another post and have voted in such a way that the sorting may eventually reflect that. That's SE post voting working as it was intended—if you want a really fair poll system we need to use STV or other voting system. As far as I can reason, using votes the way I have is the best tool we have access tool to make these posts reflect the opinion of the community.

Comment: @Caleb My understanding of the way this is supposed to work, is, you downvote an answer if you think it is "bad", for some value of bad. Not because you want another answer to get a higher score. Granted, like many things in this world, it probably doesn't work that way in practice...

Comment: @Caleb that's why some similar poll questions on other metas explicitly ask for no downvotes, and final counts use only up votes. Unfortunately, by the time I thought of that, several posts had already been heavily downvoted.

Comment: @muru I'll keep that in mind for next time. :-)

Comment: @NathanOsman it's probably a FIFO

Answer (score 35):

Yet another **chat** variation, as a shebang this time:

#### `#!/bin/chat`

Comment: Personally , I like it - distinctly Unix, easily recognizable. If someone new to StackExchange stumbles  into the chat.stachexchange.com , they will be like "Yep, that's a *nix room"

Comment: That's a great one!  I like it even better than `/dev/chat`.  I suspect this is also more recognizable to casual Unix users.  (I mean, shebangs vs. device paths.)

Answer (score 28):

#### ~​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I don't know if the system allows arbitrary names for the chat rooms. If there are restrictions, I'm pretty sure a single nonalphanumeric symbol will trigger them.

Comment: @rumtscho - well... there arent any stated in the question. and i think it would be cool.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the question states any constraints. What matters is whether the Stack Exchange chat software supports your suggestion. I'll ask the team about it, I don't think it's documented publicly. As for cool - yep, I agree about that.

Comment: OK, I asked about it. Seems like there are no restrictions other than a max length of 250 characters (but no minimum). It should work.

Comment: What about "$HOME"?

Comment: @sleblanc - what about it?

Comment: @sleblanc, proposed below....

Answer (score 26):

## talk(1)

[talk(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=talk&sektion=1) was/is a way to chat with users between Unix machines, going back to 4.2BSD (1983). **ytalk** would be another good name, as it introduced 3+-user chat, but that'd be more confusing to people who have never heard of the command.

Wikipedia has a [short history of talk and its successors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_(software)).

Comment: I think the room title should be talk(1), not just talk.

Comment: @JennyD sure, let's go for talk(1)

Comment: I really like the `talk` suggestion in preference to _chat_, but I think I prefer jimmij's variant of this, `#!/bin/talk`, which (IMO) shows clearly it's Unix/Linux land.

Answer (score 23):

Inspired by @rumtscho's excellent answer:

#### User Space

Comment: My only concern would be that people unfamiliar with Unix (or generic OS design) wouldn't get it.  That may not be a problem since it's it's the U/L chat room.

Comment: +1; but +1 more if it can be "userspace" with an ironic lack of space in the name, but lots of space to chat!

Comment: Somehow it reminds me of superuser, which is another QA site...

Answer (score 18):

#### Swap Space

Or something like.

Comment: Ooh, I like! It also carries the implication of swapping stories or ideas and the like. Very apt for chat.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't unices specific - just about every OS has virtual memory in one form or another.

Answer (score 9):

What better name for a Unix&Linux user's group than

## [`alt.unix`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/alt.unix)

??

Comment: 68k?!? that's friggin *fast*, man. ive never even heard of that!

Comment: @mikeserv Oh, perhaps if I change it to `56k` your head/hard drive will stop spinning?

Comment: thats still two thousand forty-eight baud beyond my wildest dreams.

Comment: @mikeserv maybe you'd prefer a telegraph?

Comment: it would be more comforting, yes. i stick to what i know. i like the edit, though. what ive received of it so far, that is.

Comment: Could you post each of your suggestions separately so we can vote for them please? Also, you may as well delete the first one if you're no longer suggesting it.

Comment: @terdon fixed, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I liked `alt.unix` but not `comp.unix` and wanted to vote accordingly. :)

Comment: I don't like reusing the name of the existing discussion group `alt.unix`. We'd then need to have a way to disambiguate between the Usenet group and the SE chatroom.

Comment: @Gilles do you think that's a legitimate issue? not only does *literally nobody* actually *use* Usenet anymore, but the SE chat rooms are restricted to StackExchange and many users don't know about/use them, let alone the fact that people off of SE never hear about them.

Comment: @cat it can't be "literally nobody" because even if I'm alone, it proves your claim is false.

Comment: @roaima maybe but I still don't think it's a real concern, because the chat names never leave this site

Comment: @cat oh agreed. I was quibbling over your "Usenet is dead. Film at 11" comment :-)

Answer (score 8):

Another idea from me:

> /dev/ttySE

Or some other tty, be it an existing one or something someone made up, like ttyTALK or ttyCHAT.

If you guys like the play on /dev/tty but feel that some other ending will be cooler, post your own variation, I won't see it as plagiarism.

Answer (score 8):

## `/tmp`

... where (almost) everyone can post, and (usually) others can't modify your posts.

Comment: Witty, and thus +1.  But, I doubt others will gravitate to it.

Comment: definitely not /tmp since what you say here is recorded permanently

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Not if mods or room owners feel like deleting it.

Answer (score 8):

### `/dev/stdchat` (stdchat for short)

Like stdin, stdout and stderr, we'd have a `stdchat`.

Comment: Might have [unfortunate implications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexually_transmitted_disease)

Answer (score 7):

### The Terminal

What about chat-room as the terminal?

Answer (score 7):

How about imitation of simple prompt and cursor?

#### `$_`

Comment: So, what were we talking about in the last post?

Comment: @muru What do you mean?

Comment: I was talking of `$_`, the shell variable, which holds the last parameter of the previous command (or the name of the shell if there was no previous command).

Answer (score 7):

This is a variation of [my previous post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3828/80886), but I agree with [derobert's suggestion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3831/80886) that `talk` is more appropriate in ***nix** world than `chat`.

Thus, lets join forces:

### `#!/bin/talk`

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm an outsider to your room, but I have some experience with the naming conventions of Stack Exchange chat rooms. So, here is my idea:

> The Kernel Space

Good luck in choosing! I'm interested in seeing what others will come up with.

Comment: How about just "Kernel Space"?

Comment: Nice idea but I really prefer “User Space”. “Kernel Space” would be a fine name for the mod room!

Comment: @Gilles, you should add that as an answer.  You already got four votes on it just having it as a comment!  :)

Comment: @Wildcard [Faheem already did](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3778) (otherwise I would have)

Answer (score 6):

### The Pipeline

which suggests a data flow between active agents. 
This has the problem that is sounds like a unidirectional flow. 
Some of the other communities
(e.g., Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and Server Fault)
might fight us for the right to use this.

Comment: dang. i went looking for another of yours i liked just so i could give you an extra for the *tittilating* Chat Room XX *(its a damn shame about that one)*... but i already upvoted this and... well, i like this one.

Answer (score 6):

why haven't i seen

## `/dev/urandom`

here yet?

since `urandom` is pseudorandom and cryptographically secure, and not the same as `random`.

Answer (score 6):

### `cd /chat`

Entering into chat directory!

Comment: I'd like to amend it to `cd /chat` - because otherwise everyone will going to their own local chat.

Answer (score 4):

Why not something related to system signals:

## `SIGINFO`

*From the [**FreeBSD docs**](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=siginfo&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.1-RELEASE):*

> A process may request signal information when it is catching a signal.
>        The information specifies why the system generated that signal.  To
>        request signal information in a signal handler, the user can set
>        SA_SIGINFO in sa_flags before sigaction(2) is called, otherwise the user
>        can use sigwaitinfo(2) and sigtimedwait(2) to get signal information.

Answer (score 4):

More subtle than `the-pipeline` is

## `SIGPIPE`

because it connotes that a possibly unreliable data stream (compared to the main site, chat is pretty off-topic) failed to connect if no-one's online or...

I don't know, it was just an idea.

Answer (score 3):

## The Wall

After the `wall` command, of course.

Comment: Is the allusion to Facebook deliberate?

Comment: @G-Man what? No. Dammit. I didn't think of it. Should I delete?

Comment: I'd leave it and see how the community reacts.  Delete it only if you're ashamed of having made the association and/or of *not* making the connection.

Comment: @G-Man hmm. No, we should reclaim the wall from the filthy hands of Facebook.

Comment: Then again, Pink Floyd may have it copyrighted.

Comment: What does Pink Floyd have to with walls? Anyway, we're not in music, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @muru G-Man is presumably referencing the famous Pink Floyd album ["the Wall"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wall).

Comment: @FaheemMitha I'll not hide my shame any longer. I don't listen to Pink Floyd when high (or otherwise). :P

Comment: @G-Man I remember online exchange places called “wall” well before Facebook existed (possibly even before Mark Zuckerberg existed but that was before my time as well).

Comment: Just a random reaction from a random user, but I saw "The Wall", and I thought, "What does a wall have to do with anything?  There's one on Facebook.  I stay off Facebook for a reason."

Comment: Now that I've read all 5 published volumes of [A Song of Ice and Fire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Song_of_Ice_and_Fire), I thought of—well, you already know what I thought of.

Comment: @Wildcard FWIW, I wouldn't have required an oath of celibacy.

Answer (score 3):

### The Socket

which suggests a data flow between active agents. 
Some of the other communities
(e.g., Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and Server Fault)
might fight us for the right to use this.

Answer (score 3):

### /dev/null

Where all the discards go.

Comment: That seems a little negative, and isn't true, since chat is preserved forever, so really is the opposite of `/dev/null`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes, but chat is also supposed to be "a third place", somewhere where we can relax, let our hair down and just chat.

Comment: I concur with @FaheemMitha .  /dev/null is a place where junk is sent.  The connotation is minimum 98% negative.

Comment: "Third place" means part of the site, along with main and meta. Like main and meta, it's still supposed to serve some useful purpose, including both socializing and discussion directly to do with the site. It doesn't just mean anything at all that's unwanted on the site - a lot of that would be unwelcome in chat as well.

Comment: @Jefromi no, a [third place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place) is something else. It is a place for hanging out and having informal discussions. It is third after the home and the workplace.

Comment: @terdon Exactly - it's serving a purpose (social, discussions) for people who have two places already, not just discards cast off into nothing.

Comment: @Jefromi true. I meant that it's a third place as in less serious and more relaxed. The discards bit was just a joke and filler to get the answer accepted by the system. I didn't mean to imply chat is full of crap.

Answer (score 3):

### `/dev/fd/3`

Chat is Stack Exchange's [“third place”](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/).

`/dev/fd/3` is a way to designate file descriptor 3 on many Unix variants. That's the first non-standard file descriptor (after stdin, stdout and stderr). That actually makes it the *fourth* file descriptor, but `/dev/fd/2` is taken.

(Inspired by [jimmij's proposal](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3818))

Answer (score 3):

**User Land**.

(obviously).

Answer (score 2):

I was about to suggest...

### The Panic Room

where are your LEDs start blinking. But then I remembered [where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panic_Room) I had seen that name.

Answer (score 2):

$HOME

(In case ~ won't fly)

[Need to fill this up...]

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/chat` answer so far is the best, and personally I support it. It is distinctly related to something Unix/Linux, easily recognizable. You know what else is distinctly related to *nix systems ? Shells.

My proposition is **/bin/chatsh**.

Comment: @Serg, I like yours, but did you notice [this answer](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3828/135943)?

Comment: @Wildcard yes I did notice that answer , which was posted after I've posted mine; ironically it was next to mine when I was refreshing this page. Like I said in the commend, I do like it, it's distinctly related to something originally and uniquely Unix.  Shells and scripting have been essential way of interacting with and administering a Unix system since the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

### `mount /dev/chat`

Mounting the *chat* device!

<sup>Inspired by @FaheemMitha's  [answer](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3794/66803)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

How about using **/bin/chatter** ?

Answer (score 0):

### Chatnix

This is, obviously, a reference to the *nix systems we deal with and also reminiscent of *beatniks* and the like.

Comment: I suggest "Un*x-like chat"

Answer (score 0):

> Nix Speak

Adding for the 30 char limit. blah.

Answer (score -1):

### The Command Line

What about chat as a command-line by means if which we can talk!

Answer (score -1):

### The Network Socket

which suggests a data flow between active agents. 
Some of the other communities
(e.g., Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and Server Fault)
might fight us for the right to use this.

Answer (score -1):

### Windowless room

We might have no Windows, but we have a great view.

Comment: Personal taste: I find "The Room without Windows" more pleasing.

Comment: I don't like defining “Unix” as “not Windows”.

Answer (score -1):

## SRC

The **S**tack Exchange **R**elay **C**hat, after the [traditional open chat protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat) (not particularly unix-y however). The acronym just happens to be an abbreviation for [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) that tends to come up often in our world.

Comment: But programming is off-topic here!

Answer (score -1):

A possible variant of `/dev/chat` is

#### /home/chat

Comment: I suppose that would mean "chat" is the name of the user....

Answer (score -1):

### `initctl start chat`

Starting *chat* process!

Comment: @Wildcard Done.

Comment: what do you mean "Done"?  I just saw this.

Comment: @Wildcard http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28341814#28341814

Answer (score -1):

How about considering **/mnt/chat**

Answer (score -1):

How about using [write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_%28Unix%29) for chat?

### `write user chat`

Answer (score -1):

## `/bin/cat`

echos back everything you type into it.  I know some of you will complain this is a [UUoC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), though.

Answer (score -1):

Seeing as linux stands for "`Linux Is Not UniX`" and the site is "`Unix AND Linux`" I'd think the obvious would be either
Union
Or
Self Contradicting
Or the ever most popular

> Oxymoronically Uniqs.

Which hopefully would also appeal to the OSX crowd (but not to the rest of bsdom)

Comment: One answer per post, please.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yeah, the quoteblock is the 1 answer.

Comment: ‘linux stands for "Linux Is Not UniX"’ No, this is not true. Someone might have said that as a joke, on the model of GNU (which is an acronym for “GNU is Not Unix”), but Linux is not an acronym and Linux does not try to distance itself from Unix.

Answer (score -2):

#### `swapon -a` Space

Similar to the Swap on but w/ the actual command. Might be a bit too obscure though.

Answer (score -2):

## Stalk

In the tradition of [talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_(software)) and its implementations or lookalikes ntalk, ytalk, gtalk, etalk, etc., stalk is the Stack Exchange talk.

Comment: SETalk, to avoid the unfortunate connotations of stalk?

Comment: That doesn't feel sufficiently recognizably Unixy.

Comment: @muru Oh, um, good point. I thought of the noun but not of the verb.

Answer (score -2):

/

if we can't have mikeserv's ~. A compromise towards the traditional UNIX root home dir.

Answer (score -2):

What about Chat as environment?

#### `env CHAT="Unix & Linux"`

You may also use `export` instead of `env`

Comment: why not *`export`* `CHAT=...`?

Answer (score -2):

Here is my (complicated at first) proposition - a modification of some previous answers:

#### `cat <<\EOF >/dev/tty3`

What is this?

> It simulates basic chat, i.e. redirects inputs from different users to one place: `tty3`. All users are treated on an equal footing, posts appear with fifo queue, and without formatting.

Why `3`?

> Because posts are sent to a third site on U&L (chat is third, after main and meta).

Comment: Why spoiler-type hiding of text?

Comment: wouldn't a pipe `|` and `tee` to fork make more sense and be clearer?

Answer (score -2):

### Bourne shell

After the most popular shell/command-line interpreter.

Answer (score -3):

### The Network

which suggests a data flow between active agents. 
Some of the other communities
(e.g., Super User, Ask Ubuntu, and Server Fault)
might fight us for the right to use this.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to think of this as a potential fight. Sites don't get to own all possible room names related to their topic. Other sites already have their chat rooms named (if they want): Super User has Root Access; Server Fault has The Comms Room; Ask Ubuntu just has Ask Ubuntu General Room.

Answer (score -3):

S.A.S.E. talk

primarily System Administrators of Stack Exchange, secondarily sassy; tertiarily self-addressed stamped envelope (for easy feedback!)

Comment: sassy?!?​​​​​​​

Answer (score -3):

/home/root

if we can't have mikeserv's ~. A compromise towards the Linux home dir.

Comment: `/` is way better. sorry for the retraction - but i want the vote to count for the other.

Comment: you know, `root` has home in `/root/`

Answer (score -4):

One of the chapters in the Glyn Moody book [Rebel Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebel_Code) has the chapter name:

#### Boot Time

I think that might be a good name for a chat room.

Answer (score -4):

### **echo `your question`**

Since chat are mostly about asking questions

Comment: I think `echo your discussion` would be better!

Comment: shouldn't it be `echo $your_question` rather than echoing "your question"?

Comment: @tac it should be [`printf %s\\n "$your_question"`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) but that's too wordy for a chat room name.

Answer (score -6):

This one might be a bit too Linux specific, but how about

### The Penguin Bar

Comment: I would counter with "The Beasty Bar". Just as platform specific, but adds alliteration.